# Slow AlertDialog.show(). Pre-load dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to show an AlertDialog that contains an ArrayAdapter with around a dozen items (images and text). When the app starts there is a loading screen during which multiple things are set up. One of the setup tasks is creating and building the AlertDialog.

Then, when the Dialog has to be shown, it is only needed to call `dialog.show()`. However, on the first time the dialog is shown, there is still a very noticeable delay before clicking to open and the dialog showing. This delay is gone after the first time the dialog is shown.

Shouldn't there be no delay since the dialog has already been created? What more is left for the dialog to be completely loaded (and hence no delay on first click)?

Comment: I would very much like to know why has this question been down voted. It is not a duplicate, and it's a pertinent question.

Comment: please post dialog creation and listview/recyclerview setup code.

Comment: post the dialog code

Comment: If your items are huge, then it can affect rendering. Consider using a recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

There are no codes shown so I can only make a guess. Is there any job below dialog.show() that will take a while (can be as short as 1 or 2 seconds) on the first time the dialog is shown? If so, it may block the ui thread and the dialog may not appear right after show() is called. If this is the case just put the job on another thread. For example,

```
dialog.show()
val handler = Handler()
thread(start=true) {
    DO THE JOB
    handler.post {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```